# why doesn't the function write a random word in the input field?

Tags: pyautogui

Here is the code.

```
import pyautogui as pg
from time import sleep
import random
import pyperclip

a = ['Василий', 'Петр', 'Иван', 'Сидор', 'Ануфрий']  #list
def rand_name():
    name: str = random.choice(a)  #choose a random name from the list
    pg.doubleClick(724, 417)  #click on the coordinates of the input field
    sleep(0.5)                #pause
    pg.typewrite(name)        #enter a randomly selected name
    return name
n = rand_name()               #function start
print(n)                      #examination
```

the selected word is printed to the console. But nothing appears in the input field.

why isn't my random word printed in the input field? Tell me please

Answer (score 0):

The issue are the symbols, using plane English symbols works. I don't know how to enable other symbols but here is an easy workaround:

```
def _workaround_write(text):
    pyperclip.copy(text)
    pg.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
    pyperclip.copy('')
```

So instead of typing in the text you copy-paste it.

Your final code will look like this:

```
import pyautogui as pg
from time import sleep
import random
import pyperclip

a = ['Василий', 'Петр', 'Иван', 'Сидор', 'Ануфрий']  #list
def _workaround_write(text):
    pyperclip.copy(text)
    pg.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
    pyperclip.copy('')

def rand_name():
    name: str = random.choice(a)  #choose a random name from the list
    pg.doubleClick(724, 417)  #click on the coordinates of the input field
    sleep(0.5)                #pause
    _workaround_write(name)        #enter a randomly selected name
    return name
n = rand_name()               #function start
print(n)
```

Comment: Cool. Works. I just had to comment out #pyperclip.copy(''). Then everything became as it should. Thank you friend! #pyperclip.copy('')